# Change bibliographystyle AEA to put year after author in brackets

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I already made a few changes to the original AEA bibliographystyle code. Now I want the year of publication after the authors in brackets. What should I change? This is my Latex-file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Here is an example to cite \citet{abeler2010gift} in text.

\pagebreak
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{paper}
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

The references are generated with Jabref and saved in a separate bibliography file (paper) and are formatted like this:

```
@Article{abeler2010gift,
  author    = {Abeler, Johannes and Altmann, Steffen and Kube, Sebastian and Wibral, Matthias},
  title     = {Gift exchange and workers' fairness concerns: When equality is unfair},
  year      = {2010},
  volume    = {8},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {1299--1324},
  journal   = {Journal of the European Economic Association},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}
```

The bibliography style is a modified version of the American Economic Review - Style (AEA). I uploaded the file here:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-12626400/aea.bst.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please don't show only a code snippet of a `bst` file. To give good answers it is important to have a [minimal but working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) not only to reproduce the problem but also to test our suggestions. And we need as much information as possible what is wrong with the example and what should be different. So please help us to help you.

Comment: Off-Topic: Is there a reason not to use `biblatex` + `biber`. It can be configured without `bst` hacking and has [several other advantages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't know if I understand you correctly :) You don't want me to post the whole code? I thought it is better, as I don't know exactly where the problem is. My bibliography (besides formatting) should have the following format: Author Name, Author Prename (Year). and then everything else

Comment: I want you to post a MWEB. See the links in my comment for more information.

Comment: Yes I would like to do this but I am not very familiar with coding etc. :) All of my Latex-stuff is more or less from templates. I tried to do the MWEB but it did not work or I think it did not

Comment: You want some references in my latex-file, correct? But don't you need my bibliography file or the code of it?

Comment: We need everything, that is needed to reproduce the problem. So if you are using an external `bib` file and cannot replace it, e.g., by the `biblatex-examples.bib` of `biblatex` we need a `bib` file with the entries that are valid for the example. But please have a look at the link in my first comment!

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience! I tried to integrate the necessary latex things in my original post. How should I integrate now the bibliography style code? Should I upload it?

Comment: Use `filecontents` as shown in the [community answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/9057) from the MWEB link above. If it is too large use a file hoster and add a link.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work with filecontents or I don't get it.. I uploaded the bibliography style code above with a link.

Comment: Once again: Would answers using `biblatex` + `biber` instead ob `bibtex` + `natbib`-file also be welcome?

Comment: Yes, of course. As long as it is compatible with my previous work and Jabref. Further it would be nice if this does not require too much coding-knowledge..

Comment: Still struggling with the AEA code... Does anybody have a tip where the problem lies?

Comment: @robinho Do you want *all* your 'years' to be typeset with brackets, or only the ones for `article`? (What about `book`, `incollection`, `inbook` etc.?)

Comment: hey troy. all years should be represented with brackets independent of the class. i have "article", "bookinbook", "techreport" and "book" entries

Comment: @robinho Please see my answer, and note in particular the use of `filecontents` as Schweinebacke mentioned in earlier comments. `filecontents` is especially useful when constructing an MWEB, which you can now copy-paste as a whole into your system to compile (unlike the code in your example, which is fragmented). All we ask is for you to extend the courtesy in doing the same for us when you are asking a question relating to bibliography etc in the future. It saves us a little trouble! :)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!!! Now, also the MWEB is clear - sorry I just did not get it before. Of course I understand your concerns and I will take care of them.. Best, robinho

Comment: @robinho If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). It is the TeX.SE way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect by modifying the `.bst` file, with a small caveat as pointed out by the 'comments' in the `aea.bst` file:

> ```
> Copying of this file is authorized only if either
>      (1) you make absolutely no changes to your copy, including name, or
>      (2) if you do make changes, you name it something other than
>      btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, abbrv.bst, agsm.bst,
>      dcu.bst, cje.bst, aer.bst, or kluwer.bst.
>      This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.
> ```

If you make the changes as I show below, please save it as a new `.bst` file and name it something else, like `robinho.bst` perhaps.

---

1. In the `.bst` file, find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) the `FUNCTION {output.month.year}` entry. This controls the formatting of the month and year output. So to add the desired brackets (note that this will change **all** of the formatting of the year field to include brackets), replace

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.month.year}
     {
         space month plain.space.output
         space year plain.comma "year" output.check
     }
   ```

   with

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.month.year}
     {
         space month plain.space.output
         space "(" year * ")" * plain.comma "year" output.check
     }
   ```
2. To influence the location of the year field, go ahead and find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in the `.bst` file, `FUNCTION {article}`. Replace

   ```
   FUNCTION {article}
   { output.bibitem
     author.item.check
     format.title.if.not.sortkey.check
     crossref missing$
       { space journal italic comma "journal" output.check
         output.month.year
         output.vol.num.pages
       }
       { space format.article.crossref plain.space output.nonnull
         comma format.pages plain.space.output
       }
     if$
     fin.entry
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   FUNCTION {article}
   { output.bibitem
     author.item.check
     output.month.year
     format.title.if.not.sortkey.check
     crossref missing$
       { space journal italic comma "journal" output.check
         output.vol.num.pages
       }
       { space format.article.crossref plain.space output.nonnull
         comma format.pages plain.space.output
       }
     if$
     fin.entry
   }
   ```
3. Save as `robinho.bst`. (Do so, for the reasons I mentioned at the beginning of this answer.)

Then consider the following MWEB:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{abeler2010gift,
        author    = {Abeler, Johannes and Altmann, Steffen and Kube, Sebastian and Wibral, Matthias},
        title     = {Gift exchange and workers' fairness concerns: When equality is unfair},
        year      = {2010},
        volume    = {8},
        number    = {6},
        pages     = {1299--1324},
        journal   = {Journal of the European Economic Association},
        publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}

    Here is an example to cite \citet{abeler2010gift} in text.

    \bibliographystyle{robinho}% <-----------
    \bibliography{\jobname}% <-----------
%   \nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

which gives the output:

[image]